# Menu on Android devices without a menu button

Tags: android, android-button, android-menu

I am trying to build an Android application and want a menu on it. The point is that the menu options only work with a menu button. So what about the new mobiles that don't have this button. Ok, I can use

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

and open the menu programmatically but when I touch the screen, the menu disappears.

What is the simplest way to make a static nice menu which looks like a real one but not using the menu button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe android took the menu button out for a reason, I can't imagine it would be a good idea to try and make your app look like it has a static menu button. Maybe you should reconsider you UI design and look into [action bars](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. What is your opinion for a friendliest interface? having only an action bar or keep and the menu options? is it better to open the menu options automatically or let it to the user?

Comment: How would it work opening a menu button automatically? You would need some technology to read the users mind. Maybe wait for android 5.0 for that.

The action bar is your best option. Don't try to make some menu button they took it away for a reason.

Comment: Btw android automatically puts a type of menu button in automatically. This is only to support older apps. Its not recommended to do it this way

Answer (score 2):

If a device does not have a menu button and the application creates menu options a soft menu button will be displayed. This is the case for Galaxy Nexus, HTC One X, HTC One S etc.

However you really should be looking to create an ActionBar and having your menu items inside the ActionBar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Do you suggest to have only an action bar or keep and the menu options. i just try to make the interface as friendliest as i can..

Comment: If you create you menu items in code using onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) it will create the menu items in the ActionBar (if the app has an ActionBar) or in the menu button / soft menu button if it doesn't